# Redirect Domain to subfolder /en/- but only the main Domain

Tags: redirect, typo3, typo3-9.x

I have the following issue and can't find a solution. Also I am not sure if this does work at all. 
I have two domains. `domain.de` and `domain.com`
The german site has the domain `domain.de`. As soon as the domain `domain.com` is being used the redirect shall be to `domain.com/en/`. In other words. Only if the `domain.com` is used it shall be redirected to `domain.com/en/`.

But at the same time there are other URLs. e.g. `domain.com/en/about-us/` .. or `domain.com/it/bieno/`. They all should not be affected.

Is it possible to redirect only the domain `domain.com` to `domain.com/en/` and at the same time all other URLs would still be working?

It is a TYPO3 9.x installation btw. Perhaps I can solve this in TYPO3?

Eric

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Apache (or a different webserver which supports this) you can use mod_rewrite to achieve this by adding the following to your .htaccess (replacing the domains of course):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
Rewriterule ^/?$ https://example.com/en/ [L,R=301]
```

The `RewriteCond` checks if the domain is example.com or www.example.com. If you only need it to work for example.com, you can remove `(www\.)?`. `^/?$` checks if the requested path is `/` or empty.

If you use the default .htaccess for TYPO3, you don't need `RewriteEngine On`, but you will need to add this somewhere after the existing `RewriteEngine On` and before `RewriteRule ^.*$ %{ENV:CWD}index.php [QSA,L]`. I'd add it right after `RewriteEngine On`.